# How do you run something in Google Sheets script only when a sheet is first loaded, but not for subsequent loads

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Here is my code -

```
function onOpen(e) {
        Browser.msgBox("All loads")
    var LOCscriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var LOCisFirstRun = LOCscriptProperties.getProperty('firstRun');
    if (LOCisFirstRun != "AlreadyRun") {
        LOCscriptProperties.setProperty('firstRun', 'AlreadyRun');
        Browser.msgBox("First load")
    } 
}
```

The Property value "AlreadyRun" persists when the sheet is closed and reloaded so the "First load" message is displayed only when I change the value of the firstRun Property. I expected the Property value to be empty on every load.

Is my expectation wrong or am I making a mistake?

In this form this is not useful, but when combined with a time check it think it may be. I just showed the part that fails.

Related question - Is there a way for OnOpen to know it is running at startup vs. being executed from the script editor.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you use the term sheet do  you mean an object of [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) or an Object of [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Comment: You can get an onOpen trigger to run when you open a Spreadsheet but not when you open a Sheet.  In fact I'm not even sure what it means to open a Sheet you can show them, hide them, activate them, delete them and insert them but I've never heard of someone opening them.

Comment: About `How do you run something in Google Sheets script only when a sheet is first loaded, but not for subsequent loads`, in your situation, how many users do you want to do this to? About `Is there a way for OnOpen to know it is running at startup vs. being executed from the script editor.`, it's yes. When the event object `e` of `function onOpen(e) {,,,}` has a value, it indicates that the function is run by the trigger. If the event object is undefined, it indicates that the function is directly run without the trigger.

Comment: The number of users is one for now. I see the user info can be plucked out of JSON.stringify(e), or perhaps other ways, but I understand that it might not be there in some environments.

This code worked - 
      var LOCe = JSON.stringify(e);
      if (LOCe != undefined) { 
         SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("1088 first run")
      } else {
         SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("1090 not first run")
      }

Hmmm. It won't keep the formatting. Grrr. Anyway, mnch appreciated.

Comment: It looks like I am unable to give you credit for the solution. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me when opening a Spreadheet:

```
function onMyOpen(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const fr = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('firstrun');
  if (!fr) {
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('firstrun', "true")
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("not first run")
  }
}
```

These additional functions might be useful for you:

```
function clearProps(arr=['','']) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    let ob = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();
    Object.keys(ob).forEach(k => {
      if (~arr.indexOf(k)) {
        PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().deleteProperty(k)
      }
    });
  }
}

function getProps() {
  let ob = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();
  Object.keys(ob).forEach(k => Logger.log(`${k}:${ob[k]}`))
}
```

Comment: The code you provided behaves just as mine did - It works the first time the spreadsheet is loaded with a new firstrun property but fails in subsequent loads unless the firstrun property is changed. Apparently the firstrun property value is retained after the spreadsheet is closed.
Perhaps my environment has some oddity.  The solution in the response from Cooper does work, so I'm not going to chase it further.  
Thanks for the other code. That looks useful.

Comment: But the firstRun property is changed during the first time it runs .  Its changed from null to "true" and then every time after that it displays `not first run`

Comment: Did you create an installable trigger for the onMyOpen function?

Comment: No, but I ran it as onOpen.

Comment: My apology. I think I have wasted a bit of your time. I have confuddled two things together.

Clarification -

Thing 1) Different behavior within OnOpen for the first vs. subsequent loads of a spreadsheet. This is for the simple one user case where the time never expires. There is "first Load" - one case - and the 'all the rest", the other case. This is solved by Cooper's solution. It probably always worked but I muddled the testing with …

Comment: Thing 2) Different behavior within onOpen for when a spreadsheet is first loaded vs. being run from the script editor or otherwise after the initial load.  This solved by Tanaike's solution.
 
Both work well, are short and easy to understand, and are much appreciated.

Thanks again.